# Angular using interpolation within ngClass

Tags: angular, ionic3, string-interpolation, ng-class

I want the option of adding a class to an element. Initially I tried doing `class="{{content.options.classes}}"`. This works if an "options", and a "classes" exist within a "content". However, not every content will have options and classes, which results in an error. So I wanted to create a conditional statement to add the class depending on whether or not it exists/is declared in an external object called "content".

I tried `[ngClass]="{'{{content.options.classes}}' : true}"`, but am getting an interpolation error. What would be a better way to write or go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about class="{{content?.options?.classes}}"

Comment: I have a component which is doing interpolation of classes like this
<i class="ml-3 {{ sizeClass }} spinner-border"></i>

I passed the component these classes like this
<app-activity-indicator [sizeClass]="'fas spinner-border-sm ml-0 zab aabz'"></app-activity-indicator>

But the final result is different then the order I applied the classes
<app-activity-indicator [sizeClass]="'fas spinner-border-sm ml-0 zab aabz'"></app-activity-indicator>

Difference
The classes are put in increasing order and it broke specificity of css
I wanted ml-0 to be applied after ml-3 so it can override it